# Is it possible to increase array index in a loop?

Tags: java, arrays

So my problem is that if you want to get a new calculation, the operaotr in my array should change. How can i do that? im trying this now for hours :/ this is how far i got. 
so first it starts with + and whan you choose to get a new calculation the next one should be - and so on....
so i need to switch the "operator[0]"

```
private static void mathGame() {
        char[] operator = {'+', '-', '*', '/'};
        int x;
        int y = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            int operand1 = (int) (Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1);
            int operand2 = (int) (Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1);
            System.out.println("Solve");
            System.out.println(operand1 + " " + operator[0] + " " + operand2);
            x = input.nextInt();
            // operator [1]++;
            if (x == evaluate(operand1, operator[0], operand2)) {
                System.out.println("True!");
                System.out.println("New Challange?");
                y = input.nextInt();
                //operator[1]++;
            } else if (x != evaluate(operand1, operator[0], operand2)) {
                System.out.println("False!");
                System.out.println("New Challange?");
                y = input.nextInt();
                //operator[1]++;
            }
        } while (y == 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a variable outside of your loop (int i = 0;) and then have this instruction inside the loop (maybe before "} while (y == 1);":

i = (i + 1) % 4; (4 is size of your operators array).

p.s. I think you need to give more details about your question and elaborate your question in order to make it more clear for future readers.

Comment: If it answers your question, please chose the answer as the right answer.

Comment: i always choose it but you have like a "5 min Cooldwon" on klicking it :/